# How to run asynchronous code in c# and return the value?

Tags: c#, async-await

Hi I am working c# application. I have asynchronous method which will read data from kafka. Below is my implementation.

```
public async Task SubscribeAsync(string topicName)
    {
      ConsumeResult<string, TValue> consumeResult;
      await Task.Run(() =>
      {
        consumer.Subscribe(topicName);
        try
        {
          consumeResult = consumer.Consume();
          ProcessEvents(consumeResult.Value);
        }
        catch (ConsumeException e)
        {
          logger.Error($"Consume error: {e.Error.Reason}");
        }
      });
    }
```

I am calling it as

```
 var response = kafkaClient.SubscribeAsync(topicConfigCollection.GetTopicName("TimephaseEventTopic"));
 response.Wait();
 response.IsCompletedSuccessfully.ShouldBeTrue();
```

The problem in the above code is, Whenever I debug It hangs when await comes then nothing happens. If I remove await Task.Run() then I will be able to go inside the method and I can see result of consumerresult. May I know how can I implement this correctly? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just about everything you are doing is wrong unfortunately, and its hard to know where to start with this... First question... why do you need this `async`?

Comment: Hi. Since it is receiving data from kafka(service/event bus)

Comment: May I know how to implement this in right way?

Answer (score 0):

None of these methods look *async* or returning a `Task`? so unless you want to offload to a thread and fake the *async* nature of it, then there is seemingly no need to use the *async and await pattern*

Let me suggest this synchronous code

```
public ConsumeResult<string, TValue> SubscribeAsync(string topicName)
{

    consumer.Subscribe(topicName);
    try
    {
       var consumeResult = consumer.Consume();
       ProcessEvents(consumeResult.Value);
       return consumeResult;
    }
    catch (ConsumeException e)
    {
      logger.Error($"Consume error: {e.Error.Reason}");
    }
    return null;
}
```

usage

```
var response = kafkaClient.SubscribeAsync(topicConfigCollection.GetTopicName("TimephaseEventTopic"));

if(response != null)
   response.IsCompletedSuccessfully.ShouldBeTrue();
```

**Note** : this is only an example and may not be how to use your library, yet it wont deadlock